# How to fix custome varible background image change

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I am developing a website where users can change their background image to anything they want(only a URL and on the web) I have given them some choices of my own, that work, but for some reason, the variable is not working.

I have tried

```js
'url(db)';
'url(+db+)';
'url("db")';
```

```html
<button class="bp" onclick="myown()">My Own background</button>
```

```js
function myown() {
  var db = window.prompt("Image URL");
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(db)';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JS basics and concatenating strings and variables. Variable has to be outside quotes, else it's just a string, not variable.

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + db + ')';
```

Comment: Ok thanks, I finally see my mistake in the javascript variables. I didn't know there had to be quoted. I was coming from python when you would print a variable you did not need quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate variable like this

```js
function myown() {
  var db = window.prompt("Image URL");
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url("+db+")";
}
```

```html
<button class="bp" onclick="myown()">My Own background</button>
```

add this sample url to prompt for testing

`https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/03/30/20/33/heart-700141_960_720.jpg`

You can use template literal also

```js
function myown() {
  var db = window.prompt("Image URL");
  let dummyUrl = 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/03/30/20/33/heart-700141_960_720.jpg'
  let url = `url(${dummyUrl})`
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = url
}
```

```html
<button class="bp" onclick="myown()">My Own background</button>
```